# Scala/Java: Ignore DateTimeException

Tags: java, scala, date

I am working on Day count conventions for contracts and in one of the 30/360 conventions, if a date is 28th/29th of February, I need to round it off to 30th. Since I am using LocalDate class, it throws the following error:

```
javax.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'
```

Is there some way I can bypass this exception. I want this exception to work for all the other files in my package but not for this particular use case. This is the code:

```
val newD1 = if (dateMap("month1") == 2 && dateMap("day1") == getLastDayofMonth(dateMap("year1"), 2)) **Date(dateMap("year1"), 2, 30)** else D1
```

In the 'if' statement, I produce 30th Feb. I need it to recognize it as a valid date rather than throw an exception.

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: @RC.I have added the code.

Comment: I'd instead suggest changing the job... This is madness.

Comment: Maybe you could implement a custom (and insane) Chronology?

Answer (score 0):

surround the code which throws this exception with try-catch block, and inside catch do nothing